# MonoDevelop - illegal character in Path

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When ever i try to open a file using MonoDevelop i get this message

System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
  at System.IO.Path.GetExtension (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.SlnFileFormat.CanReadFile (System.String file, MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildFileFormat format) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildFileFormat.CanReadFile (FilePath file, System.Type expectedType) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.FileFormatManager.GetFileFormats (System.String fileName, System.Type expectedType) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.IsWorkspaceItemFileInternal (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DefaultProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.IsWorkspaceItemFile (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.OpenFiles (IEnumerable`1 files) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp+c_*AnonStorey8E.<>m*_10F (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) :invoke_void_*this*__object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Please Advice

Comment: It appears you have some file in your solution with invalid characters in it?

Answer (score 2):

This was a P/Invoke marshalling bug in MD 2.4, fixed in 2.4.1.